# How to run a python script with Raspberry Pi until we stop it manually

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, automation, raspberry-pi

Currently I am working with both Raspberry Pi and Arduino at the moment. For Arduino in some cases, if we start running the script, then it will run until we stop them manually.

I am wondering if there is a way to do the same with a Raspberry Pi when using it with Python. For Raspberry Pi, when I use,

```
  sudo python myprogramme.py
```

it runs my code just once and then it is stopped. Is there a way we can run the same code with command line several times until we stop them manually (For example, in MATLAB, we have to use crtl+z to stop the running script)?
(It may be possible by using a Loop but I am wondering if we can do that without using a Loop.) Hope my query makes sense.
My point of doing it is to send continuous information from a sensor to my system.

Comment: Probably inside Arduino, there's a loop. You can include a simple while true loop in your Python code which can spit a PID based on which you can do the kill.

Comment: @ToonZ (https://github.com/ControlEverythingCommunity/BMP280/blob/master/Python/BMP280.py)   This is the code I am using at the moment. Getting no clue where to put while True statement in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments ... when you hit CTRL+C the script gets the keyboard interrupt and you can gracefully shut down.

Your code:

```
import smbus
import time

while True:
    try:
        # Get I2C bus
        bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

        # BMP280 address, 0x76(118)
        # Read data back from 0x88(136), 24 bytes
        b1 = bus.read_i2c_block_data(0x76, 0x88, 24)
        # ... and the rest of your code. 
        # add a short sleep here at the end...
        sleep(0.1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # quit
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Is there a way to use a space between the outputs in python? (By using something like Line break).

Comment: Print already puts a linebreak. If you want to put in between use os.linesep. If you want to put aspace between the outputs on your bus, send it on your bus.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code in a while statement

```
while True
    <your logic here>
```

This will run forever until you hit ctrl-C

alternatively you can do

```
my_bool = True
while my_bool
    <your logic here>
    my_bool = <check for input>
```

Comment: (https://github.com/ControlEverythingCommunity/BMP280/blob/master/Python/BMP280.py)   This is the code I am using at the moment. Getting no clue where to put while True statement in this case.

Comment: Least effort solution would be to put it right after imports and indent everything that follows.

Comment: Is there a way to use a space between the outputs in python? (By using something like Line break).